# Listings and Restructured Text

Tags: listings, restructured-text

### Background

I'm trying to define a style/language for linting Restructured Text (rst) using the listings (lst) package. This is largely for a few notes I was making but I'll submit the language definition to the listings maintainer if I can get something useful together.

### Problem

The Restructured Text syntax is not entirely linter friendly since `rst:comments`

```
.. This is a comment in ReStructured Text
```

and `rst:directives` start similarly

```
.. DIRECTIVE :: OPTIONAL ARGUMENT
   :ATTRIBUTE: VALUE

   This illustrates a directive in ReStructured Text
```

It seems `rst:directives` might map to `lst:directives`, failing that they could be mapped to `lst:keywords`.

### Home Work

The listings documentation implies there is a **listing-develop** document one can view, but any attempt to compile/open this failed `texdoc --view listings-develop` says there is no such document. Building this from the `*.dtx` document seems to have failed for me too.

There are a few questions regarding the support for "Super Collider" which I have read through but do not understand enough to adapt for Restructured Text.

### Working Example

I've included a minimal working example showing what I've managed to get so far but am not sure how to proceed from here.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{RsT}
{
 directives={example, Example, EXAMPLE},
 delim=*[directive]{..\ },
 directivestyle=\color{red}\underbar,
}[
 keywords,
 directives,
 comments,
]

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=RsT]
.. example :: ./path/to/file.ext
   :align: center
   :width:    50%
.. Example :: ../path/to/file.ext

.. comment

..EXAMPLE::Some text

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```